# Unable to get some items located scatteredly from a webpage

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm trying to get four fields from a webpage using python but the problem is the data I'm after are not within any structured html, so I can't find any way to get them individually.

[webpage address](https://colegios.es/2012/cra-la-gaznata-san-bartolome-de-pinares/)

I've tried with:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://colegios.es/2012/cra-la-gaznata-san-bartolome-de-pinares/'

def get_content(link):
    res = requests.get(link,headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    school_name = soup.select_one("h1 > a").get_text(strip=True)
    school_address = soup.find("p",text=re.compile('Dirección:\s*([^"]*?)')).text
    school_phone = soup.find("p",text=re.compile('Tel\.\s*(.*?)\s*')).text
    print(school_name,school_address,school_phone)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_content(link)
```

What I'm getting is really a mess:

```
CRA La Gaznata  San Bartolomé de Pinares CRA La Gaznata Servicios:   Jornada contínua,  Educación Infantil y Primaria   Público Dirección:    del Pino, 2  5267  San Bartolomé de Pinares Ávila  Tel. 920 270 070   Fax 920 270 070 05005981@educa.jcyl.es [google-map-v3 addmarkerlist=”del Pino, 2  5267  San Bartolomé de Pinares Ávila {}5-default.png”] CRA La Gaznata Servicios:   Jornada contínua,  Educación Infantil y Primaria   Público Dirección:    del Pino, 2  5267  San Bartolomé de Pinares Ávila  Tel. 920 270 070   Fax 920 270 070 05005981@educa.jcyl.es [google-map-v3 addmarkerlist=”del Pino, 2  5267  San Bartolomé de Pinares Ávila {}5-default.png”]
```

Output I wish to grab (second one is suburb available within name):

```
CRA La Gaznata 
San Bartolomé de Pinares
del Pino, 2 5267 San Bartolomé de Pinares Ávila 
920 270 070
```

***How can I get the four fields from that webpage?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is changing the parser to `html5lib`, that way the `<br>` tags will be correctly translated to newlines by `get_text()` method - and then it's easier to parse the text with `re`:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://colegios.es/2012/cra-la-gaznata-san-bartolome-de-pinares/'

def get_content(link):
    res = requests.get(link,headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html5lib")

    text = soup.select_one('.post-content > p').get_text(strip=True, separator='\n')

    school_name, suburb = soup.select_one("h1 > a").get_text(strip=True, separator='\n').split('\n')
    school_address = re.findall(r'Dirección:\s*(.*)', text)[0]
    school_phone = re.findall(r'Tel\.\s*([\d\s]+\d)', text)[0]
    email = re.findall(r'[^\s]+@[^\s]+', text)[0]

    print(school_name)
    print(suburb)
    print(school_address)
    print(school_phone)
    print(email)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_content(link)
```

Prints:

```
CRA La Gaznata
San Bartolomé de Pinares
del Pino, 2  5267  San Bartolomé de Pinares Ávila
920 270 070
05005981@educa.jcyl.es
```

Comment: Perfect Andrej!!! You have always been a great help. One last request- could you please add the email too? I'm way behind in regex.

Comment: @robots.txt Updated my answer. Maybe it's not the best email regex, but it works in this case. Here in SO you will find surely better regexes for email :)